# Date Format Needed (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Trying to get my date into the following format:

July 30, 2013

Please help.
Attempted to find the answer on google and could not find an exact match to what i needed. Im sure this is easy for you professionals.

Comment: What did you try, and what documentation did you read?

Comment: google shows number of solutions as  enter "date formats in vb.net" in Search Input..   http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format-vbnet

Comment: Standard http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx   Custom http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the easy question guys. I did research and couldnt find an exact match to what I needed. I will say out of the 10 questions Ive posted its good to FINALLY have one be answered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.Format`:

```
String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", #07/30/2013#)
```

or `DateTime.ToString`:

```
Dim d = #07/30/2013#
d.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

For a full list of options, look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb).

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(2013, 7, 30);
Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");
```

Thanks,
Jagjot

Answer (score 1):

`yourdate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")`